Is it normal for miniconda to store environments under `base`?
I work on a shared Mac running python 3.12, and my instance of miniconda stores all the environments in .../miniconda/base/envs/.
This has caused me some major trouble trying to install a package from a forked git repo. Just curious if this if common or if I should consider trying to rebuild my miniconda.

sounds right to me. Maybe ask the spcific problems that you had
